# Did anyone receive boons from Vishnu and turned out to be bad and had to be punished by other Gods?

Tags: vishnu, boon

It seems that a majority of people killed in scripture received boons from Siva (Asutosh - quickly pleased) or Brahma and Vishnu would then go kill them.  Did Vishnu give boons to the undeserving who had to be subdued by other Gods?

Comment: Jalandhara got a boon from Vishnu and Vishnu stayed with Jalandhara. Here Jalandhara was killed by Shiva but he didn't do any tapasya for Vishnu but Vishnu gave boons in middle of wars seeing his prowess. If you are ok with it. i will post it as answer.

Comment: Thats fine -@the destroyer  it doesn't have to be for tapasya.   I want to know if someone who turned out to be a "baddie" was in the good books of Vishnu before he turned bad and had to be disciplined by other gods.

Comment: @SK But Jalandhar was already badie when he got the boon.

Comment: @Rohit. Yes. That's the reason i stopped posting answer. @ Sk Btw, Prahlada even dethroned Indra. But Prahlada is not bad i guess.

Comment: you guys are complicating it too much.  In the overwhelming number of stories in which some baddie with boons is killed - the boons would have been given by Siva/Brahma and Vishnu would punish him.  I just want to know if roles were reverses in any cases,

Comment: @TheDestroyer Okay answer dear.

Comment: I have heard of a bad asura who was a devotee of Vishnu: Erupekshura. Idk in which scripture he's mentioned.

Comment: The answer is ShankhaChuuda who was Sudaamaa reincarnated, He did Tapasya of Krishna and then after marrying Tulasi He created Havoc throughout world with His indomitable Prowess. Then all Gods try fighting him but no avail. Then Shiva killed  ShankhaChuuda, even MaahaaKaali tried killing ShankhaChuuda, but he could be killed only by Shiva and after breaking of Tulasi's chastity. So Naaraayan himself said that I will cast semen in Tulasi and after that Shiva Killed ShankhaChuuda